# matplotlib 3d contour_plot colour levels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, 3d, contour

How can I change the number of discrete colour levels in a 3d matplotlib plot_surface?

e.g

```
    normalisation = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=numpy.amin(Z), vmax=numpy.amax(Z))
    axis.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap=matplotlib.pyplot.cm.Greys,norm=normalisation)
```

But with N colour levels over the normalization range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for the normalization instead, where n is the number of levels:

```
cmap = matplotlib.pyplot.cm.Greys
bounds = numpy.linspace(numpy.amin(Z),numpy.amax(Z), n + 1)
normalisation = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
```

Comment: Don't colourmaps require normalised input so how can boundary norm, which says it returns integers, give a normalisation for a colourmap? Also why are there 2 inputs to boundary norm, isn't bounds required to be equal to clap.N for the colour to bound mapping to work? Thanks for answering, I just don't comprehend the BoundaryNorm class.

Comment: If you look at the docstring for Colormap.__call__, you can use either integers from 0 to Colormap.N (i.e. the number of colors in the colormap) or floats: "For floats, X should be in the interval ``[0.0, 1.0]`` to
            return the RGBA values ``X*100`` percent along the Colormap line.
            For integers, X should be in the interval ``[0, Colormap.N)`` to
            return RGBA values *indexed* from the Colormap with index ``X``."

Comment: As for why bounds doesn't have to be equal to ncolors (cmap.N, in this case, but you can choose lower values if you want to use less of the colormap), BoundaryNorm scales the integers by a factor of (len(ncolors) - 1) / (len(bounds) - 2).

Comment: Thanks Amy Teegarden.
This runs, and gives more colour quantisation levels than matplotlib.colors.Normalize
But not the level of colour quantisation levels that are specified in e.g bounds or cmap.N .